# How to upload images to an Amazon ec2 linux web server from Android?

Tags: android, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webserver

I have a AWS Ec2 linux instance and I'm wondering how could I upload images to that server? I've tried encoding a selected image into a base64 string and passing that string to the server API. From the server, I've tried to place the contents into a folder, but nothing has worked. Do I need to set certain permissions for this to work or is there something else I need to do?

This is AS code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button buttonchoose;
    private Button buttonUpload;

    private ImageView imageView;

    private EditText editTextName;

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    private String UPLOAD_URL = "http://52.39.80.117/upload.php";

    private String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    private String KEY_NAME = "name";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonchoose = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
        buttonUpload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

        editTextName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        buttonchoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void showFileChooser(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData()!=null){
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try{
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==buttonchoose){
            showFileChooser();
        }

        if(v==buttonUpload){
            uploadImage();
        }
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    private void uploadImage(){

        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        loading.dismiss();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //Converting Bitmap to String
                String image = getStringImage(bitmap);

                //getting image name
                String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

                //Creating parameters
                Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                //Adding parameters
                params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
                params.put(KEY_NAME, name);

                //returning parameters
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

This is my API code:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    require_once('conn2.php');

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM photos ORDER BY id ASC";

    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    $id =0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        $id = $row['id'];
    }

    $path = "photos/$id.png";

    $actualpath = "http://52.39.80.117/photos/$path";

$sql = "INSERT INTO photos (name,path) VALUES ('$name','$actualpath')";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($image));
    echo "successfully uploaded";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
}else{
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you show us some code you tried?

Comment: My code is posted. Any help is appreciated. I'm starting to feel that its a permissions problem on my Ec2 instance.